# Verifying ClearCase files have been labeled properly

Tags: clearcase, label

My company uses ClearTeam Explorer for version control. Sometimes when either I or a co-worker apply a label, we get an error message. Today my comrade got

"An error occurred during a ClearCase operation.
 CRMAP7009: CCRC command "WriteProperties" failed:

CCRC WANServer: Error: No permission to perform operaton "change event".
 CCRC WAN Server:Error: Mustbe one of : user associated with event, object owner, element owner, VOB.."

**According to the above message, you would think the operation failed, correct**?

However, it appears looking at a random sampling of the files that everything was labeled correctly.

It is alarming to get this message and then find out it appears to have done what it said it didn't??? - There will always be lingering doubt unless you can verify that every single file was labeled properly.

Early on, I ignored this error and continued making labels for various versions. Now, I want to verify because I have lots of GB of files and there is no way I can hand verify everything.

Offhand, it seems like I want to make a view based on the date the label was created (maybe months ago) and then have a script to show any files that don't have a label.

Comparing files between 2 labels might work also provided at least one of the labels has "all the files" labeled?

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> According to the above message, you would think the operation failed, correct?

No, and there is an [APAR PM79463](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/entdocview.wss?uid=swg1PM79463) in progress on that one.
(an APAR is an [Authorized Program Analysis Report, or APAR, that is: "a formal report to IBM development of a problem caused by a suspected defect in a current release of an IBM program"](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21424131))

(CTE = " ClearTeam Explorer")

#### Error description

> User tried to apply label to an element on CTE, and error messages were shown although label was applied.
>
> So user tried to apply label to an element on HomeBase in native    client after logging in Windows as the same user as user who was used in CTE, and succeeded to apply label without errors.
>   If executed user is not the owner nor creator of the object but belongs the same group of VOB owner, the issue was occurred on CTE although the operation was succeeded on HomeBase.
>
> Error messages are shown on pop up window as follows.

```
  CRMAP7009: CCRC command 'WriteProperties' failed:
  CCRC WAN Server Error: no permission to perform operation 'change event'
  CCRC WAN Server Error: Must be one of : user associated with event: 
    object owner, element owner, VOB owner, member of ClearCase group
```

---

So you can try and put labels through the ClearCase HomeBase gui, which seems more robust.

Comment: You're the man, thanks! Having this kind of feedback gives regular users some hope :-)